# Understanding the meaning of ${n \choose n/2 } $

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, asymptotics

I am trying to study the asymptotics of $f(n) = {n \choose n/2}$, $g(n) = n!$ and $h(n) = {n \choose 3 }$.

First, $h(n)$ is easy as $h(n) = O(n^3)$ and we see that since $n! \approx \sqrt{2 \pi n} (n/e)^n$, then

$$ g(n)/h(n) \approx n^{-2.5} (n/e)^n = \dfrac{ n^{n-2.5} }{e^n } $$

HOwever, I dont see a way to prove $g/h \to \infty$ to prove what is intuitively clear: $n! >> n^3$. What I am having difficulties is with $f(n)$. My thought is to write

$$ f(n) = \dfrac{ n! }{(n/2)! (n/2)! } = \dfrac{ n(n-1)(n-2).... 1 }{(n/2)^2 (n/2-1)^2 ...1} $$

And I see that $f(n) $ is approximately $0$ because powers in the denominator are getting higher. However, this is wrong, since for instance ${1000 \choose 500} $ is a very large number. What is happening here?

Comment: Isnt ${n \choose n/2 } = n^{n/2} $ ?

Comment: $$\frac{h(n)}{g(n)}=\frac{\binom{n}3}{n!}=\frac{\frac{n!}{3!(n-3)!}}{n!}=\frac1{6(n-3)!}<\frac1{n-3}<\frac1n\overset{n}\longrightarrow 0$$

Comment: By Stirling's formula, $$
f(n) \sim \frac{{2^{n + 1/2} }}{{\sqrt {\pi n} }}.$$

Comment: Prof. Scott nice to see you again! What a wonderful surprise!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your first question, note that
$$\frac{g(n)}{h(n)} = \frac{6n!}{n(n-1)(n-2)} = 6(n-3)!$$
No need to use Stirling's approximation.

---

For your second question your misunderstanding comes from not actually counting how many factors are in the numerator and denominator. Although the denominator does have higher powers of $n/2$ and $n/2-1$ and so on, the numerator still has larger terms like $n$ and $n-1$. And both the numerator and denominator has $n$ factors (if you write $(n/2)^2$ as $(n/2)(n/2)$). There are a lot of things going on here, so it is difficult to discern the behavior just by looking at that expression.

Stirling's approximation can help a lot here.
Since $n! \approx \sqrt{2 \pi n}(n/e)^n$ and $(n/2)! \approx \sqrt{2\pi n/2} (n/(2e))^{n/2}$ we have
$$\binom{n}{n/2} = \frac{n!}{(n/2)!(n/2)!} \approx \frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{\pi n}}2^n$$